# Finding if a vector of pair<string,string> contains pairs that match on the first string

Tags: c++, search, vector

Right, I know the title is pretty convoluted, so I'll try to explain my situation:

I have a vector of pairs of strings, `std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` which contains pairs of **names** and **surnames**.

Is there a go-to simple way of using `find` or `find_if` to get all pairs in my `vector` that match only on the first part of the pairs?

**For example,** if my vector contains the pairs:

```
John Doe
Ivan Ivanovitch
Richard Stallman
```

is there a way to use `find` or `find_if` to check if my vector contains any `pair`s that match with the first name `John`, disregarding the last name (which I will use later on)?

Suppose that my vector only contains distinctly different names and surnames and there's never pairs that have the same `first`, meaning no two `John`s or `Richard`s.

Comment: If you know that `find_if` exists, what's stopping you from looking up literally *any* example of how it's used and see how to solve your problem?

Comment: `find_if` and a lambda will do what you want.

Comment: Could you please ask one question at a time? First you ask about finding "all pairs", and then you ask about "checking whether the vector contains any pair".

Comment: Reading documentation would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::pair<std::string, std::string> const & elem)
                                     {
                                          return elem.first == "John";
                                     });
```

You can compare the return value with `vec.end()` to see if the find succeeded